# Displaying fields on report in a paragraph format in ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to display a list of values from a dataset in SSRS 2008 r2. I created a dataset that pulls a list of serial numbers from a shipper number parameter. I can get the S/Ns to display on the report, but they are in a column format which takes multiple pages. I am trying to put them in a paragraph format separated by commas. ie - s/n1, s/n2, s/n3, ...  I found an article on this site using Join but I couldn't adjust it to work for me.

Here is the query I am using to pull the data:

```
SELECT A.fserial
FROM smsm2mdata.dbo.serial AS A
JOIN shmast AS B ON B.fshipno = A.fshipno
WHERE B.fshipno = @fshipno
```

And I put the field into a list tablix on the report

This is the last hurdle before I can publish the report ... Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the the Join() function isn't working is probably that you are passing a single value into it instead of an array. This will occur if you just add the function into a freshly created tablix, because those are normally set up to show data row-by-row, instead of aggregated by set.

You have a few different options. One is to use a lookup function with the join() function. Usually lookup retrieves values from a dataset based on criteria, but in this case you just want everything. So you can make the criteria something that will always be true, such as 1=1 in the first two parameters in this example:

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, fields!fserial.Value,"YourDataSetName"),",")
```

I believe that formula could even just be used in a textbox if you wanted to. You could also alter you sql query to produce the results in paragraph form right off the bat, making it so that you don't have to do anything special in SSRS. This uses a kinda esoteric sql feature but it is useful to know this specific application:

select stuff((select ','+ A.fserial
    FROM smsm2mdata.dbo.serial AS A
    JOIN shmast AS B ON B.fshipno = A.fshipno
    WHERE B.fshipno = @fshipno for XML path('')
    ),1,1,'')

I think you could even get away with using a Join() function without a LookupSet() function if you were grouped properly and had removed the details section from you tablix.

Comment: Neither of the first two options worked.  After research, I determined that the LookupSet and Stuff functions are for SQL 2016 (unfortunate, makes me want to upgrade).  I tried the third option, but can't seem to get the join  function to work.  Keeps throwing an error.

Comment: The second option is a purely SQL based option - you would change your query. It does not require any SSRS features. The first option uses the lookupset and join functions, both of which have been in ssrs since at least 2008r2.

Comment: @ahartman if you are getting error messages, showing what you are trying and then showing the error you are getting can be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: When I paste the join command into the expression editor this is what I get:

Comment: @ahartman you didn't paste any message there. It can also be helpful to add the expression you are using and the error message in the body of your post instead of in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, edit timed out. When I paste the join command into the expression editor this is what I get:  hmm, can't seem to paste a picture.  Anyways, LookupSet is underlined in red and bubble help says 'unrecognized identifier'.  When I preview the report it errors with: The Value expression for the textrun 'fserial.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0)' contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'LookupSet is not declared.  I am new at this. Just finished SSRS training.

Comment: @ahartman Are you sure you are using SSRS-2008-r2? Maybe you are using SSRS-2008 instead? That error does seem to indicate that it is not available in your version, but it was definitely available in 2008-r2, which is what you have your question tagged as. If it is not available, I would try the SQL-based solution instead. You would replace your dataset query with the query I provided above.

Comment: OK, shame on me.  I checked the disk SQL 2008 Standard.  Not R2. I reset the expression and replaced the query with the one above.  When I executed it, I got this error - An error occurred while executing the query. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.

Comment: I was missing an extra select - I've edited the query, please try again. @ahartman

Comment: That did it.  I had to add a space after the comma to get the word wrap correct.  Thanx!!